# Woocommerce related products - only show in stock related products

Tags: woocommerce, product, stock

I'm trying to filter the products shown in "related products" in woocommerce so that it only outputs related products that are in stock.

I've tried editing the "related.php" template as below - but it ain't working!

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'              => $orderby,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
    'meta-key'             => '_stock_status',
    'meta-value'           => 'outofstock',
    'compare'              => '!='
) );
```

I'd appreciate any help

Many thanks

Answer (score 10):

None of the answers given here worked for me (I believe the `woocommerce_output_related_products_args` filter mentioned does not accept meta_queries), and I wanted a solution that didn't use an SQL query, so I put together the solution below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'mysite_filter_related_products', 10, 1 );
function mysite_filter_related_products( $related_product_ids ) {

    foreach( $related_product_ids as $key => $value ) {
        $relatedProduct = wc_get_product( $value );
        if( ! $relatedProduct->is_in_stock() ) {
            unset( $related_product_ids["$key"] );
        }
    }

    return $related_product_ids;
}
```

Hope that helps someone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: It creates below error.
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_in_stock() on bool in

Answer (score 0):

I think You have done this task, but if anyone having this issue then they can use this code to show only "in stock" product on related products, change into `related.php`:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(

  'post_type'            => 'product',
  'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
  'no_found_rows'        => 1,
  'posts_per_page'       => $posts_per_page,
  'orderby'              => $orderby,
  'post__in'             => $related,
  'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
  'meta_key'             => '_stock_status',
  'meta_value'           => 'instock',
  'compare'              => '!='
)
);
```