# Hide out of stock related products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce I would like to hide *Out of Stock* products from **Related products** in single product pages. Is it possible?

Any track is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021**

You can use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query', 'alter_product_related_posts_query', 10, 3 );
function alter_product_related_posts_query( $query, $product_id, $args ){
    global $wpdb;

    $query['join']  .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id ";
    $query['where'] .= " AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value = 'instock' ";
    
    return $query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> Now **we need to remove "related products" cached data** deleting the related transients to flush this cache *(thanks to [@Cody Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13396408/cody-rees))*.

**There is 2 ways to do it:**

1). The **easiest** way:

Go to admin Woocommerce > Status > Tools > WooCommerce transients and press on "Clear transcients".

2). The other way targeting specific related transients to be deleted:

Add the following code and save:

```
add_action('init', 'delete_related_products_cached_data');
function delete_related_products_cached_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}options WHERE `option_name` LIKE '_transient_wc_related_%'");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

**Run it only once** by browsing any page of your web site and remove it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help : But It doesn't work ; I've cleared the cache but I didn't see any change.

Comment: I know your code is correct; But I don't know why nothing happen to my site!!! I've changed so many times this code! But I didn't see any change! What's wrong?

Comment: @sarahmiller I haven't anything better for instance.

Comment: It doesn't work with backorder products. They are shown despite the _stock_status = instock

Comment: Answer  has been updated thanks to @CodyRees

Comment: Your solution is not working. I applied the 2021 update and then cleared the transient cache data but it still doesn't work

Comment: @svelandiag for me and for CodyRees it works… So maybe something else is making trouble in your case…

Answer (score 13):

None of the answers given here worked for me (I believe the `woocommerce_output_related_products_args` filter mentioned does not accept meta_queries), and I wanted a solution that didn't use an SQL query, so I put together the solution below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'mysite_filter_related_products', 10, 1 );
function mysite_filter_related_products( $related_product_ids ) {

    foreach( $related_product_ids as $key => $value ) {
        $relatedProduct = wc_get_product( $value );
        if( ! $relatedProduct->is_in_stock() ) {
            unset( $related_product_ids["$key"] );
        }
    }

    return $related_product_ids;
}
```

Hope that helps someone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: +1 but this using this solution will not replace the removed related products with other related products, so you'll end up with less than the number of related products you wanted. E.g. if you want 4 to always display, but a particular product's related products contain 2 out of stock products, then only 2 related products will display.

Comment: To fix that, one could add more code, before the return, to check for the count of $related_product_ids and query for some more products, if the count is less than the desired number.

Comment: Doesn't work either for the latest versions of woocommerce. The filter `woocommerce_related_products` doesn't only receive the `$related_products_ids`argument.

Comment: It works, Thanks dmoz and sarah miller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to hide out of stock products from related products.

Add the below to functions.php – this will hide out of stock products from related products.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', function( $args )
{
    $args = wp_parse_args( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'meta_query' => array (
           'key' => '_stock_status',
           'value' => 'instock'
    )
    ), $args );
    return $args;
});
```

The posts per page line can be removed, but its useful as a quick of visualising that this has worked on your related products block.

Comment: Doesn't work, tested thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

For those who didn't find solution:
Tested on Woocommerce +6

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'vahids_related_products', 10, 3 );
function vahids_related_products( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ){
    $in_stock_product_ids = (array) wc_get_products( array(
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'limit'        => -1,
        'stock_status' => 'instock',
        'return'       => 'ids',
     ));

    return $in_stock_product_ids;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working code from here.  Add this code to your functions.php and you will see that our of stocks products will not be seen in related product block. Code is from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978253/15213069

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'mysite_filter_related_products', 10, 1 );
function mysite_filter_related_products( $related_product_ids ) {

    foreach( $related_product_ids as $key => $value ) {
        $relatedProduct = wc_get_product( $value );
        if( ! $relatedProduct->is_in_stock() ) {
            unset( $related_product_ids["$key"] );
        }
    }

    return $related_product_ids;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

create a function and hook it to related products hook of woocommerce like:

```
function dont_show_outofstock( $is_visible, $id ) {
    $product = new wC_Product( $id );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
    $is_visible = false;
    }

    return $is_visible;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'dont_show_outofstock', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It crashed my site and after adding this snippet I don't see related products and also footer of the page!!!

Comment: That filter doesn't take/pass those arguments